# ruby how to pass values from a hash

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and want to understand how to pass values corresponding to keys in ruby.
I have a hash in rubylike below-

```
instance1
shutdown_port: 1234
startup_port: 1678
instance2
shutdown_port: 2234
startup_port: 2678
```

I want to pass `shutdown_port` and `startup_port` for each instance to a method but do not want to mix `shutdown_port` & `startup_port` values.

Something like, `if keyname = shutdown_port`, pass corresponding value and `if 
if keyname = startup_port`, pass corresponding value.

Comment: "I have a hash in rubylike" - that doesn't look like a ruby hash, at all.

Comment: actually  I am writing a chef cookbook and this is what I will pass in my .kitchen.yml. I need to read "shutdown_port" and "startup_port" for each instance

Comment: It's not a valid yaml either. Even if it was, you should spare us from this implementation detail. You'll parse it as a hash eventually. Post a valid hash.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby actually allows for [keyword argument as of Ruby 2](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments), which will parse a Hash. (Provided you used `YAML.parse(file)` correctly to get a Hash.)

In your case, you want something like:

```
# method takes keyword args
def idk(startup_port:, shutdown_port:)
  p "#{startup_port}, #{shutdown_port}"
end

# which you call like this:
idk({ startup_port: '22', shutdown_port: '80' })
# or without explicit hash
idk(startup_port: '22', shutdown_port: '80')
```